# Floating Div above content

Tags: html, css

I'm not a CSS expert. Everytime I think I understand layout, something crops up that confuses me. Currently, I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <input id="searchQuery" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
  <br/>

  <div id="searchSuggestions">
    <!-- search suggestions will be dynamically populated -->
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <!-- Rest of site content goes here -->
</div>
```

When a user is entering stuff into the search field, I am providing them with search suggestions. I have this working. My problem is, as the suggestions appear/disappear, it pushes the content up and down. I want the content to stay in place. I would like for the search suggestions to appear beneath the searchQuery field, yet look like a layer on top of the content. What CSS properties must I use to make this happen?

THank you!

Comment: What "content" is getting moved? The page content below the search box?

Comment: [`position:absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) might be helpful. Can we see your current CSS?

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: @showdev beat me to it...`#searchSuggestions { position: absolute;}`

Comment: @dan - Yes, the content below the search box.

Comment: A bit of an aside, but if you are constantly being confused by new aspects of CSS as you encounter them, it might be really helpful for you to read [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/). It is dry, but really, it is helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the search parent div to be {position: relative}, and the search results child div to be {position: absolute}. The search results, being positioned absolutely, will be pulled out of the regular flow and be placed at the top left of the first parent div that is positioned relatively.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position